# How to move variable out of local scope in service-worker

Tags: javascript, event-handling, service-worker

I am sending data with Broadcast Channel API from source code to service-worker: `firebase-messaging-sw.js`.
Then I retrieve it in service-worker with the following function:
`const mainChannel = new BroadcastChannel("main-channel"); mainChannel.onmessage = (data) => {console.log(data)}`

Question is that how can I use **data** retireved from `mainChannel.onmessage` function to use it in another function?

I have tried to declare global variable and then assign data to it and then use it inside another function but it doesn't work and I can't figure out why. Here is what I tried.

`````
let translateData = {}
const mainChannel = new BroadcastChannel("main-channel");
mainChannel.onmessage = (data) => {
  translateData = data;
}

self.addEventListener('push', (event) => {
  messaging.onBackgroundMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log(translateData)
    storeMessage(payload.data);
    const notificationTitle = payload.data.title;
    const notificationOptions = { body: payload.data.body };
    return event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions));
  });
});````
`````

Comment: Basically like that, yes. How does it not work? Where are you firing the main-channel message? Do you receive that message before the firebase background message?